# Как считать из узла XML файла, если имена дочерних узлов одинаковые?

Tags: c#, xml

Считываю узлы XML файла в XmlNodeList.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

doc.Load(filePath);
XmlNodeList cellList = doc.SelectNodes("//Row/Cell");

foreach (XmlNode node in cellList)
            {
```

XML файл содержит самую разнообразную информацию, а так же множество узлов ROW.

```
<Row>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s69"><Data ss:Type="Number">1</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s69"><Data ss:Type="Number">340054288</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s69"><Data ss:Type="String">ИВАНОВ  К. С.</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s69"><Data ss:Type="String">НОВОСТРОЙКА  28 ГА</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s69"><Data ss:Type="Number">271</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s69"><Data ss:Type="String">108.8200</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s69"><Data ss:Type="String">2015-061195</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s69"><Data ss:Type="String">DDS 232</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s70"><Data ss:Type="DateTime">2017-09-05T00:00:00.000</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
```

Как считать информацию из дочерних узлов - узла ROW в переменные для последующей записи в базу данных? Затрудняюсь, так как все дочерние узлы одноимённые.

Пытаюсь считывать так:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(filePath);


            //XmlNodeList cellList = doc.SelectNodes("//Workbook/Worksheet/Table/Row/Cell");
            XmlNodeList cellList = doc.SelectNodes("//Row/Cell");


            int counterOfRow = 0;

                // посчитаем количество узлов ROW:
                foreach (XmlNode node in cellList)
                {
                    counterOfRow = counterOfRow + 1;

                }



                foreach (XmlNode node in cellList)
                {

                    for (int i = 0; i == (counterOfRow - 1); i++)
                    {

                        string iDNumber = node.Attributes[i].Value;
                        string iStringNumber = cellList[i].InnerText;
                        string iAccountNumber = cellList[i + 1].InnerText;
                        string nameAbonent = cellList[i + 2].InnerText;
                        string address = cellList[i + 3].InnerText;
                        string house = cellList[i + 4].InnerText;
                        string debt = cellList[i + 5].InnerText;
                        string counterData = cellList[i + 6].InnerText;
                        string typePu = cellList[i + 7].InnerText;
                        string setupData = cellList[i + 8].InnerText;

                        textBox1.Text = iDNumber + '\r' + '\n';
                        textBox1.Text = iStringNumber + '\r' + '\n';
                        textBox1.Text = iAccountNumber + '\r' + '\n';
                        textBox1.Text = nameAbonent + '\r' + '\n';
                        textBox1.Text = address + '\r' + '\n';
                        textBox1.Text = "address" + '\r' + '\n';
                    }
                }
```

Почему-то counterOfRow остаётся равным нулю, то есть изначально даже не находит узлы ROW.

Comment: Если порядок узлов не строгий, то - никак. Как узнать чему принадлежат разные Cell? У некоторых из них всё одинаковое, только значения разные.

Comment: @XelaNimed у всех узлов ROW порядок последовательности дочерних узлов одинаковый.

Comment: В этом случае вместо `foreach` используйте `for` и по индексу элемента соотносите `Cell` с необходимым свойством/переменной.

Comment: @XelaNimed for (int i = 0; i = ???; i++) но мне неизвестно количество узлов ROW? Или нужно сначала посчитать их количество с помощью foreach?

Comment: Измените XPath, т.е. сначала выберите Row в XmlNodeList, а затем в цикле выбирайте у каждого Row его Cell. Для вставки в БД Вы должны каким-либо образом определить имеется ли в БД уже такая запись. Но зачем Вам кол-во узлов Row?

Comment: Зная количество узлов ROW, можно делать так: 
                foreach (XmlNode node in cellList) {
                       for (int i = 0; i == (counterOfRow - 1); i++)
                    {
                        string iDNumber = node.Attributes[i].Value;
                        string iStringNumber = cellList[i].InnerText;
                        string iAccountNumber = cellList[i + 1].InnerText;
                        string nameAbonent = cellList[i + 2].InnerText;
                        string address = cellList[i + 3].InnerText;

Comment: Чтоб не гадать - обновите ответ, добавив в него уточняющую информацию: что Вам нужно сохранить в БД, структуру XML и т.д. и т.п..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// посчитаем количество узлов ROW:
foreach (XmlNode node in cellList)
{
    counterOfRow = counterOfRow + 1;
}
```

Что за бред? У коллекции `XmlNodeList` есть свойство `Count`.

```
Console.WriteLine(cellList.Count); // количество узлов
```

Однако, это нам не нужно.

---

С учётом других ваших вопросов, вот законченный пример кода, извлекающий информацию из вашего xml.

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();

var manager = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
manager.AddNamespace("ns", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet");
manager.AddNamespace("ss", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet");

doc.Load(filePath);
var cellList = doc.SelectNodes("//ns:Row/ns:Cell", manager);

Console.WriteLine(cellList.Count);

foreach (XmlNode cellNode in cellList)
{
    var styleId = cellNode.Attributes["ss:StyleID"].Value;

    var dataNode = cellNode.SelectSingleNode("ns:Data", manager);

    var type = dataNode.Attributes["ss:Type"].Value;                    
    var text = dataNode.InnerText;

    Console.WriteLine(styleId);
    Console.WriteLine(type);
    Console.WriteLine(text);
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```